# How do I write semidirect product symbol " ⋊ "?

Tags: symbols, fonts

I am trying to write in a *.nb file the following syntax:

$G \rtimes H $ or 
$G \ltimes H $

Comment: Write it out as "\:22c9" or "\:22ca"

Comment: @JasonB. Doesn't work for me (Windows 10).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Works in v10.4 and v11.1 under Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please be aware that these characters are not regarded as an operator but as part of the symbol. So if you use it in code and don't put a space between it, it will be one symbol

```
Head[G⋊H]
(* Symbol *)
```

If you put a space between it, then it will be regarded as the normal product between 3 variables

```
FullForm[G ⋊ H]
(* Times[\:22ca,G,H] *)
```

If you simply want to *write* it in a text cell, I guess it is easier if you assign a shortcut to it. Search this site for `InputAliases` to learn more about this:

```
SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], InputAliases -> {"spl" -> "⋉", "spr" -> "⋊"}]
```

Then you can use <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>spl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>spr</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to type them.